# Instantiate Spring Bean using parametrized Constructor in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to declare a component with a parametrized constructor but it is throwing me an error. Is there any way to resolve this situation?

I can have a default constructor to avoid the situation. But, my Business requirement says only to have parametrized constructor. Is there any work around?

```
@Component
public class Employee {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int yearsOfExperience;
    private String designation;

    @Autowired
    public Employee(**String** firstName, **String** lastName, **int** yearsOfExperience, **String** designation) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.yearsOfExperience = yearsOfExperience;
        this.designation = designation;
    }
```

Error: Could not Autowire. No Beans of String is found. The bold text is an error out with a shared message.

Comment: I don't know the exact usecase but addressing it in a generic way.Employee is a model class.If you try to configure it as a bean ,one instance of Employee will be created which I dont think you want in your application.Second thing if you want to configure Employee as a bean then configure with @Bean.

Comment: Something like this.If you want to configure multiple Employee bean use @Qualifier `@Bean
 public Employee  getEmployee() {
  return  new Employee("first-name","last-name",4,"designation");
 }`